# can't scrape table element from https://www.screener.in/

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape some financial data from this [website](https://www.screener.in/screen/raw/?sort=name&order=&source=&query=Market+capitalization+%3E+350&limit=50&page=1) using the following code

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import urllib.request
from pandas import DataFrame
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import ssl
from IPython.display import display
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

l=('https://www.screener.in/screen/raw/?sort=name&order=&source=&query=Market+capitalization+%3E+350&limit=50&page=1')
urlpage=urllib.request.urlopen(l)
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(urlpage,'html.parser')
coulmn=[]
dta=[]
coulmn.append(' ')
soup.find('div',{'class':'responsive-holder fill-card-width'}).findAll('tr')
```

but it can't find anything it just returns an empty list

Comment: I believe this is because the URL request doesn't have session information. Try opening your URL in the incognito window and you will see that website asks you to register (instead of showing you the data you are looking for). You must pass your active Cookie information with the request (or create another request, that will log you in - extract session cookies and add those cookies to the next request with your data)

Comment: thanks, now I can see what the problem is.

Comment: can you refer me to any link/article for the procedure to send cookie information  in scrapy

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. This should help you. P.S. it's created using `requests` and `bs4` modules. If you need exactly `scrapy` to handle this task, then maybe I can create another example using it (someday)

Answer (score 2):

First of all - you are using the `Beautiful Soup` library instead of scrape.

I've created an example for you of how to make a logged-in request using Python and use BeautifulSoup for data extraction.

I have tested it on `Python 3.8.0`

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import re

# url

login_URL = 'https://www.screener.in/login/'
data_URL = 'https://www.screener.in/screen/raw/?sort=name&order=&source=&query=Market+capitalization+%3E+350&limit=50&page=1'

# credentials

form_data = {
    'username': 'letiwoh199@ichkoch.com',
    'password': 'qweqweqwe'
}

# request config

form_csrf_key = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
cookie_csrf_key = 'csrftoken'
cookie_session_key = 'sessionid'
content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324'

# get form_csrf_value & cookie_csrf_value

get_login_request = requests.get(login_URL)
get_login_request_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(get_login_request.text, 'html.parser')
form_csrf_value = get_login_request_soup.find('input', {'name': form_csrf_key})['value']
cookie_csrf_value = re.search(cookie_csrf_key + '=(.*?);', get_login_request.headers['Set-Cookie']).group(1)

# login into account & get cookie_session_value

form_data[form_csrf_key] = form_csrf_value

post_login_request = requests.post(login_URL, form_data, headers={
    'Cookie': cookie_csrf_key + '=' + cookie_csrf_value,
    'Content-Type': content_type,
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    'Referer': login_URL
}, allow_redirects=False)

cookie_session_value = re.search(cookie_session_key + '=(.*?);', post_login_request.headers['Set-Cookie']).group(1)

# get data from the desired page

get_data_request = requests.get(data_URL, headers={
    'Cookie': cookie_csrf_key + '=' + cookie_csrf_value + ';' + cookie_session_key + '=' + cookie_session_value,
    'Content-Type': content_type,
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
})

get_data_request_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(get_data_request.text, 'html.parser')
table_rows = get_data_request_soup.find('table', {'class': 'data-table'}).findAll('tr')
```

If you execute `print(table_rows[1])` after this code, it will output:

```
<tr data-row-company-name="Zydus Wellness">
<td class="text">1.</td>
<td class="text">
<a href="/company/ZYDUSWELL/consolidated/" target="_blank">
            Zydus Wellness
          </a>
</td>
<td>1862.50</td>
<td>62.49</td>
<td>11851.49</td>
<td>0.27</td>
<td>1.74</td>
<td>305.42</td>
<td>381.58</td>
<td>14.70</td>
<td>6.04</td>
</tr>
```

You can change the `data_URL` variable in order to obtain data from different pages.

Additionally, you can change `username` and `password` in the credentials section. I have created a temp account for this example.

Comment: thank you soo much. I also found one answer which worked and I want to share. go to inspect element then to networks reload the page copy cURL of the first link. There are websites that convert cURL to python code just paste that code in your IDE and it works

Comment: [link](https://www.screener.in/company/500243/) in this link I have added some custom ratios from edit ratios I am using cookies and it is working fine for the previous problem but here it is not extracting my ratios only the default ratio please help I tried my solution and even your solution but nothing seems to work I want to extract Cash Equivalents from the ratio table

Comment: You can't see Cash Equivalents because it's fetched using API (xhr request). This is the link to get your custom ratios: `https://www.screener.in/api/company/1604/quick_ratios` You need to request it with your cookies. The `1604` is the warehouse ID that you can get from source code of the page, e.g. ```<div data-company-id="1791"
     data-warehouse-id="1604"
     data-user-is-registered="true"```. Hope this will help you.